# C++ performance improvement by binding returned value to const reference

Tags: c++

Consider I have the following function:

```
std::string foo();
```

Is there an advantage of doing this:

```
const std::string& ref = foo();
```

over this:

```
std::string val = foo();
```

Or is the compiler smart enough to do optimizations in the second case.

Comment: There should be no difference, but if it matters to you, you should measure it.

Comment: Just an FYI if `foo()` is returning a locally created string then you should not return it by reference.

Comment: If your string variable is a const reference, move semantics cannot be used on it; could that actually decrease performance, depending on how the string is later used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likley NRVO will trigger. Lets give an example

```
std::string foo()
{
    std::string s1;
    // fill up s1 with content
    return s1;
}

void bar()
{
    std::string s2 = foo();
    std::cout << s2;
}
```

This will neither do a copy, nor a move, but rather the return value (s1) will be constructed at s2 directly. This is called return value optimization, and it means you should not return by const reference, or capture by const reference as some sort of performance hack, it will either not work, or slow thing down, depending.